# validate latitude and longitude jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have walk through much to find valid regex in javascript to validate latitude and longitude separatly.

but in vain..

tried the following but not working..

```
    var latlngVal = /^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6},-?((1?[0-7]?|[0-9]?)[0-9]|180)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/;
    if (!latlngVal.test(this.value)) {
       //logic
    }
```

can anybody tell me the easiest way to validate the latitude and longitude entered in the 
textbox.

Or is there any mvc annotation to validate latitude and longitude?

Comment: Why use only regex for this?
You could use a regex for the latitude's form, but also use a regular number comparison for the value. Would probably save you a lot of trouble, rather than creating overly complex regex'.

Comment: I'd add some whitespace (before, before and after ',', after). BTW, what is not working?

Comment: Its giving  'Latitude and Longitude are not correctly typed'  for 24.791722 which is correct

Answer (score 0):

I made it with following..

```
$(".longitude").focusout(function () {
    debugger;
    var lngVal = /^-?((1?[0-7]?|[0-9]?)[0-9]|180)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/;
    if (!lngVal.test(this.value)) {
       //logic
    }
});
```

for latitude validation use

`var latVal = /^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/;`

Comment: This is actually incorrect since it will accept values between 180 and 181: both -180.791722 and 180.791722 are accept which are obviously invalid.  Same goes for latitude, values of -90.791722 and 90.791722 are accepted.  You could fix these by doing additional checks if you don't want to complicate the reges:

    if (lat > 90 || lat < -90) return false;